# CKEditor5 / Angular errors when including SourceEditing plugin

Tags: angular, typescript, svg, ckeditor5

Using Angular 18 + CKEditor 5 + Material Design:
When I add the SourceEditing plugin to the CKEDITOR config, it crashes.

Has anyone seen the errors below?

**ERRORS ON COMPILE**

> ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/align-bottom.svg:1:0 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
>
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

(happening for every SVG file that CKEditor has)

**HTML**

```html
<ckeditor [editor]="Editor" [config]="{ plugins: [sourceEditing], toolbar: [ 'bold', 'italic', 'sourceEditing' ] }" />
```

**TYPESCRIPT**

```TypeScript
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import { SourceEditing } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-source-editing';
```

export class SomethingSomethingComponent implements OnInit {

```
public Editor = ClassicEditor;
public sourceEditing = SourceEditing;

constructor() {
}

}
```

Comment: clear npm cache and install again, it could be install issues

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom build in order to enable sourceEditing feature.
You can create custom build from this official site: https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/
avoid premium plugins if you don't have license.
after the zip file downloaded make a folder with src level  below is the directory example

```
├── ckeditor5
```

│   ├── build
│   ├── sample
│   ├── src
│   ├── ...
│   ├── package.json
│   └── webpack.config.js
├── node_modules
├── src
├── ...
└── package.json

After every thing in place you need to install node-packages for editor and provide the path of directly in the component .ts file to that build for example:  import Editor from 'ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor';

Comment: I am not sure if I have to go that route.     According to this CKEDITOR documentation page ( https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/source-editing.html ) ... all I need to do is a simple :   npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-source-editing

Comment: also that document refer to make the custom build if you are using any FE framework and want custom plugins https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/integrations/angular.html